# Is 一日千秋 a chengyu?

Tags: grammar, simplified-characters, chengyu

Is 一日千秋 a chengyu? I have tried searching for it using google with mixed results.

If it is a chengyu, what is its grammatical function?

Comment: look up in Japanese dictionary

Comment: 一日千秋 is the Japanese equivalent of 一日三秋

Answer (score 2, accepted):

一日千秋 is a Japanese idiom. When I searched for the term on Google, almost all of the websites were in Japanese, and the top Chinese website explains it is a Japanese idiom.

- [一日千秋是什么意思 - 沪江](https://www.hujiang.com/jpciku/je4b880e697a5e58d83e7a78b/)

According to the website above, 一日千秋 means:

> 一日三秋。（1日が非常に長く感じられること。待ちこがれる気持ちが著しく強いこと。）

This reads as:

> The feeling that it takes too long for a day to end. The strong sentiment to wait for someting.

<sub>I think the *一日三秋* on the website is a typo...</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Never heard of 一日千秋.

Most likely, you're thinking of the idiom "**一日三秋**" , which came from an expression "一日不見，如隔三秋" -- "Not seeing (each other) for just one day, feels like it has been three autumns (three years)"

"一日三秋" express the sentiment of "time seems moving painfully slow when you are waiting anxiously"

Answer (score 1):

It's not a chengyu. We always say:

> 一日不见，如隔三秋

The meaning is you've been missing someone，and finally you see him or her, then that is always said.

Where did you find this expression?

Comment: Wikipedia actually includes it as a Chinese chengyu
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chengyu